# Yii Framework: Undefined variable model when checking if guest

Tags: php, yii

We have a actionSearchType in our User Controller as follows:

```
public function actionSearchType()
{
        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest == true)
            $this->render('login');
            else 
        $this->render('search_type');
    }
```

Our actionLogin in our User Controller is as follows:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model= new Users();

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']))
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
 $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
                    }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

The goal is to ensure that only authenticated users can execute the options on the search type view.  When I run this page, I receive an error stating `Undefined variable: model`.

A snippet of the login view is as follows:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>
```

What steps must be taken to remedy the above error and properly check to ensure we have an authenticated user?

**update**
I changed actionSearchType to render the Login Widget per below:

```
 public function actionSearchType()
{
        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            $this->widget('ext.LoginWidget');
            else 
        $this->render('search_type');
    }
```

This indeed resolved the error initially seen.  A new problem is that there's no styling of the login widget when it renders.  Should I echo my  tags with appropriate stylesheet classes, or is there a bit more elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function actionSearchType() {
  if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    $this->redirect('/user/login');

  $this->render('search_type');
}
```

Notes:

- to do something when user is guest, simply use if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) { statement }
- to do something when user is logged in, simply use if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) { statement }

in the second code, public function actionLogin(), I think you have 2 more closing curly brackets than needed. Anyway, the login action should look like this:

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $formModel = new Login_Form; // Login_Form.php should be in models folder
    if (isset($_POST['Login_Form'])) {
        $formModel->attributes = $_POST['Login_Form'];
        if ($formModel->validate() && $formModel->login()) {
            $this->redirect('/'); // replace / with stuff like Yii::app()->user->returnUrl
        }
    }
    $this->render('login', array(
        'formModel'=>$formModel,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering the view redirect to the user login page / action so you don't have to recreate it.

```
$this->redirect('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in `search_type` you are referencing the variable `$model` which you do not hand over to the [render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail) function. You need to define that variable otherwise the view will create an Exception.

I don't know which Model/Class your `search_type` view is expecting but you will need to initialize it before you hand it over to the view like this:

```
$this->render('search_type',array(
   'model' => $model,
));
```

Here a good read about this topic: [Understanding the view rendering flow](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/)